# Twitter API cursor based pagination (JSON issue) PHP

Tags: twitter

as you know Twitter has posted a new cursor based pagination for some API methods.

Currently, I'm facing a problem when encoding the json object because the cursor itself is actually a 64-bit numbers and not supported for json encoding in PHP.

```
next_cursor 1299072354878293926
```

Any solution for this? I can't believe why didn't Twitter just return string for it...hmmp

thx

Comment: Why would they return a string if it's an integer? Not their fault PHP's JSON encoding doesn't handle it right...

Comment: exactly...that's what I'm trying to figure out...I mean...that should at least work for all isn't it...

if there is any better way rather than hacking the value?

Answer (score 1):

PHP 5.2+ should convert 64-bit numbers to floats, which is better than previous versions of PHP (which would just convert it to the maximum 32-bit value). Best bet is to move to a 64-bit version of PHP, but updating to PHP 5.2+ will at least get you up and running.

Comment: it does covert to floats..but i need the number to allow me navigate through the data...i"m using the PHP 5.2+...Converting to 64-bit seems impossible to me, though it will definitely solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with 32 bit system, you could convert the cursor to string using regex and then use it for further requests.

Here's PHP function that I am using to achieve this:

```
function jsonIntToStr($json){
$pattern = "/\"next_cursor\":([0-9]+),/";
$replace = "\"next_cursor\":\"$1\",";
$new_json = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $json);
$pattern = "/\"previous_cursor\":([0-9]+),/";
$replace = "\"previous_cursor\":\"$1\",";
$new_json = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $new_json); 
return $new_json; 
}
```

and you could use it like:

```
$json_result = json_decode(jsonIntToStr($twitter_response));
```

Got it from [twitter development talk google group](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/msg/7a93458731e3d52d).

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.4.0 (currently in beta), it is possible to use the fourth parameter of [json_encode](http://php.net/json_decode) and set it to `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`.