# JSON string outputs a float value

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am parsing a JSON response (twitter api - cursor value) and what should be a string value seems to be a double value when I output it with PHP.

Any idea how I get the real string value?

Comment: Posting the response in question, the php code, and the displayed result would be helpful

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't really a double value? I mean converting a string to double if the string isn't a number sounds strange to me... what is the JSON data?

Comment: ok maybe I am wrong. The json looks like : ...,"next_cursor":1324265698590457809}

Comment: when I echo it it shows something like 1.3227481350289E+18

Comment: Well it is definitely not a string and I guess the output is this way because the number is big. BTW where is the need to output this number? It is of no use for a user, isn't it?

Comment: this was just the way I wanted to show you. In my code I am using this value in the rest of my function...

Comment: Same question, answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662376/twitter-api-cursor-based-pagination-json-issue-php/1696053#1696053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curser value is too large for 32bit PHP installs to handle with json_decode. Someone sent me `preg_replace( '/next_cursor":(\d+)/', 'next_cursor":"\1"', $json );`. Running that before json_decode will convert the json int to a string before conversion.

**Update:** Twitter now provides next_cursor_str values that are strings instead of integers so using `preg_replace` is no longer needed.

Comment: "Scientific notation is a way of writing numbers that accommodates values too large or small to be conveniently written in standard decimal notation." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 1):

To convert a float (or any type of variable) to a string, you can use one of these:

```
$value = 5.234;

// Using type casting
$str_value = (string)$value;

// Using strval()
$str_value = strval($value);

// Using concatenation to a string
$str_value = $value . '';

// Using sprintf
$str_value = sprintf("%s", $value);

// Using setType
setType($value, 'string');
$str_value = $value;
```